# Which module facilitates looking up database schemas of custom content type?

Tags: database, charts

I am setting up some reports using DB API to query custom content fields, and rendering them in tables and charts. I am looking for a way to easily look up the names of tables and fields in the Drupal DB.

**My Question**: Is there a Devel-type module that provides an easy reference of the live DB schema?

Currently I'm using drush sql-cli and/or phpmyadmin, so the solution should be something simpler than that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Schema Module](http://drupal.org/project/schema) can handle that...

> - Schema documentation: hyperlinked display of the schema's embedded documentation explaining what each table and field is for.

I confess I haven't tried it but the module page mentions

> the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database that the Schema module uses to inspect the database.

so I imagine it has the functionality you're looking for, plus inspection of the live db if you need it.

Or if you don't mind wading through a large krumo array you can always use [`drupal_get_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7)

```
dpm(drupal_get_schema());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list db tables with

- mysql: show tables;
- psql: \d

However, a better way to get field information would be via a Drupal module and use:

- [field_info_fields](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7)
- [field_info_instances](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7)
- [field_info_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7)
- [field_info_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)

To get the detailed field and instance information.

Table information for each field is also stored in the info structure.